PWA cached videos throwing "internet connection appears to be offline"
I'm creating a PWA with Vue and a CMS that includes a number of videos.
I'm using vite-plugin-pwa which uses workbox to pre-cache the local application files and then uses a CacheFirst strategy to cache all of the CMS JSON, images and videos, effectively making a completely offline experience.
My vite.config.js looks like this
    VitePWA({
      registerType: 'autoUpdate',
      injectRegister: 'auto',
      workbox: {
        globPatterns: ['**/*'],
        cleanupOutdatedCaches: true,
        runtimeCaching: [
// store asset requests to cache image and video assets
          {
            urlPattern: /^https:\/\/s3\.amazonaws\.com/,
            handler: 'CacheFirst',
            options: {
              cacheName: 'cms_assets',
              expiration: {
                maxEntries: 1000,
                maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 2, // 2 years
              },
              cacheableResponse: {
                statuses: [200],
              },
              rangeRequests: true,
            },
          },
// store api requests to cache JSON data
          {
            urlPattern: /^https:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.cms\.com/,
            handler: 'CacheFirst',
            options: {
              cacheName: 'cms_apis',
              expiration: {
                maxEntries: 500,
                maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 2, // 2 years
              },
              cacheableResponse: {
                statuses: [200],
              },
              rangeRequests: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      manifest,
    }),
  ],
 

This works 99% of the time, but every so now and then I receive the following error
"Failed to load resource. The internet connection appears to be offline"
and the videos (only) will then fail to play, throwing
"Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotSupportedError: The operation is not supported"
for the play() attempt. This kills all of the video in the application meaning that the whole app needs to be restarted (swiped away) at which point the video will start working (offline) again.
My current thinking is that this is due to the CacheFirst strategy attempting to go online to download one of the video range requests (note rangeRequests: true in the plugin config) - this is sporadic.
I thought maybe I needed to somehow precache all of the CMS content and use a CacheOnly workbox strategy but not really sure how to proceed with that - maybe as part of the npm build?
Would be great to see if anyone has previous experience of this and the right approach to solve it
Testing in iOS 17.4.1

Update: going online when in this broken state does allow the videos to play while online however if i go back offline, the videos always try to load from the network rather than the cache until i restart the pwa
